# Error when creating Directory and creating files using touch in UNIX

Tags: file, unix, directory

I am trying to create a directory structure in Unix. I made the directory using mkdir command with -p option but when i use "touch" to create files i get hit with the "No such file or directory error"
[image: The hierarchical structure]

The code i tried .

```
mkdir -p livingthings{birds/{flyingbirds,nonflyingbirds},plants,animals/{mammals,reptiles}}
touch livingthings/{birds/{flyingbirds/{stork,eagle,eider},nonflyingbirds/{kiwi,ostrich,penguin}},plants/{carrot,cabbage,daisy},animals/{mammals/{jaguar,dog,tiger},reptiles/{alligator,skink,turtle}}}
```

This is the error which pops out 
[image: Error]

Help much appreciated.

UPDATE :
After adding the "/" i get one error now that is telling

```
touch: cannot touch 'livingthings/animals/reptiles/turtle': No such file or directory .:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you missed the slash after livingthings in mkdir -p livingthings/{birds..... not mkdir -p livingthings{birds.... Because of this it creates a directory named livingthingsbirds instead of livingthings/birds. But then in your touch command u r using livingthings/ so thats why it cant find that directory.

Comment: Please check if reptiles folder is created when u executed the mkdir command, I guess not. So you have to check your mkdir command once again. Here is what I tried in my terminal and it just works fine.
first, 
mkdir -p livingthings/{birds/{flyingbirds,nonflyingbirds},plants,animals/{mammals,reptiles}}
and then

touch livingthings/{birds/{flyingbirds/{stork,eagle,eider},nonflyingbirds/{kiwi,ostrich,penguin}},plants/{carrot,cabbage,daisy},animals/{mammals/{jaguar,dog,tiger},reptiles/{alligator,skink,turtle}}}